# PHP Assign Value from dropdown selection

Tags: php, html

I have this loop coded to create a dropdown with the numbers 0-30.

```
<td style="text-align:left;">
    <select id="iPhone12Case" name="iPhone12Case">
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<=30; $i++) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php
}
?>
    </select>
</td>
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the value of I to work in my calculations on an order processing form.

I assign the variable using

```
$iPhone12 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['iPhone12Case']);
```

but if I try to output $iPhone12 * 15 for example the answer is always zero.

Comment: Simple test, add a `print_r($_POST);` so you can see whats in the data passed to you.

Comment: Also Check the `<form>` tag has a `method="POST"` attribute

Comment: Also before using ANY values from the form at least check that it exists using `if (isset($_POST'iPhone12Case'])) {`

Comment: you need to somehow send it to the server... via ajax or via GET or POST request... please clarify your code and how are you sending it to the server to calculate it

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you select is wrapped in a `form` element with `method="POST"`. You should also use `isset` to make sure it exists.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <td style="text-align:left;"><select id="iPhone12Case" name="iPhone12Case">
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select></td>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['iPhone12Case'])) {
    $iPhone12 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['iPhone12Case']);
    printf($iPhone12 * 15);
}
```

Comment: But also make sure, that you are not creating invalid HTML - as this example does. A form can not be nested into a table row like that - either the form needs to go around the whole table, or it must be contained within a single table cell.

Comment: Oh yes, of course.